# convert str(time) to date format with other data included

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I have data in the format:

```
['12,Dec,2014, 02,15,28,31,37,04,06', '9,Dec,2014, 01,03,31,42,46,04,11',...]
```

I am trying to convert the str(date component) into date format using:

```
   new_data =''
   for line in date_data:              
       line = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(line), "%d,%b,%Y")
       new_data = new_data + line
   print(new_data)
```

At least the 'routine recognises the date part, but can do nothing with the numbers. How could I overcome this problem please. I have tried using % for as many characters as follow the date without success. I have never used the time module before.
What I want to achieve is to associate each number with the date it appears. I am trying to teach myself parsing of text files by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is separated from the numbers by a comma followed by a space, then you could use `line.split(', ', 1)` to split the line into two parts.
Then you could call `datetime.datetime.strptime` to parse the date.

```
import datetime as DT
date_data = ['12,Dec,2014, 02,15,28,31,37,04,06', '9,Dec,2014, 01,03,31,42,46,04,11']

for line in date_data:
    part = line.split(', ', 1)
    date = DT.datetime.strptime(part[0], '%d,%b,%Y').date()
    numbers = map(int, part[1].split(','))
    print(date, numbers)
```

yields

```
(datetime.date(2014, 12, 12), [2, 15, 28, 31, 37, 4, 6])
(datetime.date(2014, 12, 9), [1, 3, 31, 42, 46, 4, 11])
```